# Plurals with referenced formatted string

Tags: android, android-xml

I have 2 strings messages:

values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="number_of_seconds_left_one">%d second</string>
<string name="number_of_seconds_left_other">%d seconds</string>
<plurals name="numberOfSecondsLeft">
    <item quantity="one">@string/number_of_seconds_left_one</item>
    <item quantity="other">@string/number_of_seconds_left_other</item>
</plurals>
```

values/ru-rRU/strings.xml:

```
<string name="number_of_seconds_left_one">%d секунда</string>
<string name="number_of_seconds_left_other">%d секунды</string>
<plurals name="numberOfSecondsLeft">
    <item quantity="one">@string/number_of_seconds_left_one</item>
    <item quantity="other">@string/number_of_seconds_left_other</item>
    <item quantity="few">@string/number_of_seconds_left_other</item>
    <item quantity="many">@string/number_of_seconds_left_other</item>
</plurals>
```

I'm getting the following IDE error in the `values/ru-rRU/strings.xml` file for `<item quantity="one">`:

> The quantity 'one' matches more then one specific number in this locale (1, 21, 31 .. ) but the message did not include a formatting argument  (such as %d). This is usually internationalization error.

It's working fine if I set the string directly in the plural item:

```
<plurals name="numberOfSecondsLeft">
    <item quantity="one">%d секунда</item>
    <item quantity="few">%d секунды</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d секунды</item>
    <item quantity="many">%d секунды</item>
</plurals>
```

Android studio 4.0.1